# MLP neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to write a code in R to predict the currency rate of USD/EUR  using MLP neural Network 
I facing a problem with the input of the function neuralnet it keeps giving me an error of

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

This is the code that i have written so far

```
library(readxl)
ExchangeUSD <- read_excel("C:/Users/GTS/Desktop/ML project/ExchangeUSD.xlsx")
plot(ExchangeUSD$`USD/EUR`)

#traning and test data 
trainset <- ExchangeUSD[1:350,]
testset <- ExchangeUSD[351:500,] 

set.seed(12345)
library(neuralnet)
nn <- neuralnet(`USD/EUR`~ "YYYY/MM/DD"+"Wdy",data = trainset)
```

the data-set contains 500 rows and  3 columns the first column is YYYY/MM/DD and it contains the date from October 2011 until October 2013 (500 data). the second column is Wdy and it contain the weakly days the final column is the USD/EUR and contains the currency rate 
[a part of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W26TS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `nn <- neuralnet(USD/EUR ~ YYYY/MM/DD + Wdy, data = trainset)` (i.e. remove the quotes from the variable names).

It would be even better if you rename the `USD/EUR` as `USD` and `YYYY/MM/DD` as `date`.

Comment: thanks for your response I have changed them and the following error appeared
"  Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments" 
is it right to put the USD as an input or should i change it ?

Comment: What error? Can you show me the `head()` of the data?

Comment: head(ExchangeUSD)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  date                Wdy     USD
  <dttm>              <chr> <dbl>
1 2011-10-13 00:00:00 Thu    1.37
2 2011-10-14 00:00:00 Fri    1.39
3 2011-10-17 00:00:00 Mon    1.38
4 2011-10-18 00:00:00 Tue    1.37
5 2011-10-19 00:00:00 Wed    1.38
6 2011-10-20 00:00:00 Thu    1.37

Comment: May be making the Wdy as numeric may help you and change the date format. I don't think neuralnet can take such input 2011-10-14 00:00:00. Change the date into numeric may help you out. After modeling you can back transform those into original date and day format.

Comment: Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
              this is the error

Comment: Comments are not for posting code, data, or error messages, neither for asking follow-up questions. Since the answer resolved the error reported in your question, please *accept* it and open a **new** question with the new issue (it's free, after all)